# Fetch distinct values from 1 table by comparing 2 tables with 2 different column names

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is the use case scenario for the SQL query:

There are 2 tables "Login" & "User". Login only contains the username whereas User contains both the username and the Fullname of the users. The column names are as below:

Table **Login**

- L_User

Table **User**

- U_User & F_Name

Although the name of the columns L_User and U_User is different but they both contain the same data as in both contain the username of the users. I want to fetch distinct records from login.L_User and their corresponding Full Name from User.F_Name by comparing/matching values between login.L_User & User.U_User.

So, for a record in L_User if there is a matching record in U_User then display the data in the following format:

```
**L_User**  **F_Name**
DS001         Dane Smith
JH006         John Howard
```

### EDIT

This is what i have tried.

```
Select DISTINCT login.l_user, user.f_name
  from login full join user on login.l_user like user.u_user
 where login.l_user is not null
    OR user.u_user is not null
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  This is a basic SQL operation.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What were the problems with it?

Comment: This is what i have tried. Select DISTINCT login.l_user, user.u_user from login full join user on login.l_user like user.u_user where login.l_user is not null OR user.u_user is not null;

Comment: I am getting all sorts of results from both tables and not just the distinct value from login table and the corresponding full names of those users from the user table.

Comment: `from login full join user on login.l_user like user.u_user` Shouldn't you use = (equals) instead of `like` ?

Comment: I have tried both = and Like both don't suffice the requirement.

Comment: Please refer to this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=063144fa31fbb6e3ce34ca9b5edf7935). What have I missed? Note that Oracle did not let me create a USER table so I changed the table name to USERS.

Comment: Please ignore the names of the columns and the tables...thats just an example. The actual table names are different.

Comment: @irish show us some real data sample.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Login.L_User, User.F_Name
FROM Login 
INNER JOIN User 
ON Login.L_User = User.U_User
```

Comment: Thanks but I get zero results when I run this query.

Comment: @irish so, are you sure that L_User and U_User contain the same data? Try adding ```TRIM``` -> ```TRIM(Login.L_User) = TRIM(User.U_User)```